# "Is there any HTML5 audio player that supports .au format? or any external plugin?"

Tags: angular, html, audio, media-player

I need to add support for .au format audio file. Please suggest the audio player that supports this format. HTML5 audio tag doesn't provide support for .au format.

Till now I've used HTML5 audio tag, embed tag, added microsoft media player, added vlc player.

```
<audio controls> 
<source src="example.au" type="audio/basic"> 
Your browser does not support the audio tag. 
</audio>
```

and used microspft media player :

```
<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
<param name="filename" value="example.au">
     <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
     <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
     <param name="autostart" value="true">
     <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
     <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
     <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
     <embed src="example.au" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310">
</object>
```

This doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far in your question, to make it clearer for people trying to answer it.

Comment: @Lennart Till now I've used <audio controls>
  <source src="example.au" type="audio/basic">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>. But it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats This page shows the supported media formats, and unfortunately I haven't been able to find the Au file format there. Therefore I assume that it isn't supported. Looking at wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format) for the Au file format, it seems to me that it is pretty old as well.